# I have custom CSS to disable radio buttons in my Qualtrics survey. However I would like them displayed on ONE particular page?

Tags: css, radio-button, qualtrics

I am using the following CSS code to hide radio buttons in my Qualtrics survey.

```
input[type=radio]{
visibility: hidden;  
}
```

However I would like them displayed on the first page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use visible for that

```
$("p").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Replace "p" with your selector

Comment: Unfortunately I can only enter JavaScript for each page, is this still what I'd do?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an oldish question, but this solution works in Qualtrics' unique environment.

I assume you are putting the style tag in the HTML section of the given question. If you put it only on the 2nd block, then it won't apply on the first. I think it's because it's not in the HTML header section (you don't have access to that) but it's in the body tag. Its scope is therefore limited.

Whether that's the reason or not, I replicated it in a survey I'm building. Any styling done in the block only applies to that block. If you wanted to limit radio buttons per question within a block, you would need a different solution, though.